# Modifying user access UI elements properties from another window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on a project in WPF that requires me to build a color picker Window that changes the color of certain UI elements inside the user control upon which the color picker Window pops up.How can I access and modify the properties of UI elements present inside a User Control from another Window?

Answer (score 0):

Make a function in your MainWindow and whenever the colour in the colourPicker-Windows changes, call the function like this: Application.Current.MainWindow.();